# Can I run php mysql in google app engine

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine

I am planning to create a facebook canvas app using php sdk.

Google app engine providing free account so I am planning to do it.

But still there is a problem , right now google app engine support only java and python.

Is there any way to run php and mysql in google app engine?

Comment: It sounds like you are using AppEngine only because it is 'free?' The pricing changes that were announced recently at Google I/O places tight restrictions on what you will get for free: http://www.google.com/enterprise/appengine/appengine_pricing.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP can't run natively on the App Engine. But, there is an open source tool called [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/), a 100% Java implementation of the PHP language (requires JDK 1.5).  Since the App Engine now supports Java this means you can use Quercus to run PHP scripts on the App Engine.

Comment: this answer is outdated - Google now supports PHP natively see comment below http://stackoverflow.com/a/16627324/32726 or https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/

Answer (score 7):

Okay, I am two years late, but from today PHP is [officially available](https://gaeforphp.appspot.com/) on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 5):

You can run PHP scripts on App Engine in the JVM with Quercus; however, it's still not possible to use mySQL; you'll need to use the App Engine datastore. This will require rewriting any code that touches a database, so existing PHP scripts aren't going to work without a lot of hacking.

Note: relational database support is on the App Engine roadmap, but no one knows exactly when it will be available, or whether the relational database made available will be mySQL.

Answer (score 4):

Google App engine now supports PHP run time. Check official documentation here - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/

You can check this blog for details on announcement - http://spsneo.com/blog/2013/05/18/php-on-google-app-engine/

Answer (score 2):

Quercus is not as good as running PHP natively and it has known issues. As i understand you are starting to create an application, so i suggest using  Python in appengine. Its very easy to get started.

If you have LAMP based application in mind and if you do not want to learn a new language check out [Amazon Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).

I suggest making a decision based on the strengths of the platform and flexibility you need.

Answer (score 0):

Google has officially announced its support for PHP on Google App Engine (GAE)

How to host PHP web application on GAE for free is explained in this [tutorial](http://www.tinywall.info/2013/10/12/google-app-engine-php-windows-getting-started-hello-world-example-gae-development-deploy/).