# Codeigniter and Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, codeigniter

I've made my entire site using the [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) framework, and it is working well without any hassles (Note I'm using MySQL in the website).

I've been told now to try and get it on to the Google servers as they are excellent for scalability. I just have one huge problem, is there any way or step by step tutorial that helps me do this as I've read up on Quercus which allows for the php to run but I haven't found something explaining how to use the Codeigniter framework with the Quercus.
Please any help or push in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I run php mysql in google app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275337/can-i-run-php-mysql-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We announced Native PHP support for Google App Engine at I/O.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/

Answer (score 3):

After Google announced native PHP support I decided to deploy CodeIgniter on Google App Engine. It works natively, tough certain extensions to the core must be done in order to use PHP Runtime API.
I've started writing a series of articles you might want to check out which document and clarify the process of deploying CodeIgniter natively.

http://blog.programming4design.com/codeigniter-on-google-appengine-for-php/

Comment: URL seems to be broken and now just points to the main site. :(

Answer (score 2):

PHP is being added natively to App Engine, maybe this year, but I'm not sure when. The App Engine Team announced this on the parntership event at Paris last week.

Comment: Bastien Legras - Cloud Platform Solution Engineer at Google announced it, I can email him on the subject if you want the exact date of the release

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter works fine on Google App Engine's PHP.

Working Demo at : http://ci-on-gae.sasidhar.com/

Source files for the entire above demo site are in Github at : https://github.com/sasidhar/codeigniter-gae-app